# pick up string with specific pattern in R using gsub

Tags: regex, r

`"CATARACT; #&#22823;&#33151;&#39592;~2010"`

I need to pick up the `&#22823;&#33151;&#39592;` in R using `gsub`, it is actually unicode that starts with `&#` followed by a five digits number and then ended with `;`.

I know how to get rid of these unicode using the following:

`gsub("&#[0-9]+;","","CATARACT; #&#22823;&#33151;&#39592;~2010")`

But how can I retain these unicode using `gsub`?

#### Edit 01

My desired output is `&#22823;&#33151;&#39592;`.

#### Edit 02

Thanks for the answer, but what if the pattern is not always like that, I need to pick up the unicode no matter where they are:

`"CATARACT; #&#22823;&#33151;&#39592;~2010;CATARACT; #&#22824;&#33152;&#39593;~2010"`

Comment: What's your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

E.g. using `gregexpr` and `regmatches`:

```
ex <- "CATARACT; #&#22823;&#33151;&#39592;~2010;CATARACT; #&#22824;&#33152;&#39593;~2010"
m <- gregexpr("&#[0-9]+;", ex)
(r <- regmatches(ex, m))
# [[1]]
# [1] "&#22823;" "&#33151;" "&#39592;" "&#22824;" "&#33152;" "&#39593;"

paste(r[[1]], collapse="")
# [1] "&#22823;&#33151;&#39592;&#22824;&#33152;&#39593;"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
 gsub("(^\\D*)((&#[0-9]+;)+)(.*$)", "\\2", x)
```